# Word choice for salutation in a formal email to your PhD adviser, Is *Dear Boss* appropriate?

Tags: phd, advisor, etiquette, email, france

I am a first year PhD student in France, born and raised in India. It is not customary in here where I am doing my PhD to call one's adviser *boss* but I do, partly due to my reluctance to call her by the first name, partly attributed to the culture in which I am brought up. As one comment suggested, "Dear professor" would have been an appropriate choice but she doesn't have any teaching duties and is a full time researcher. I would have used "Dear Madam" if I were in India but no one here use that. I think "Dear Dr. X" is too formal and no one here use that either. Many prefer "Hi X" but I think that is too informal. 
Now that I am writing an email, Is *Dear Boss* an appropriate salutation? If not, what would be an appropriate salutation in a formal email?

Comment: _due to my reluctant to call her by the first name_ Would you explain a little bit why?

Comment: @scaaahu Well, I am not comfortable in calling by her first name. I think it roots from the culture I am raised.

Comment: Unless your advisor is very strict about formalities, you might eventually reach a point where most emails sent to your supervisor will be informal in style. This does not mean that the content is however.

Comment: @PatW I'm not sure I ever started from formal communication with my supervisor. I would expect normal to be about the verbal equivalent of 'smart casual'.

Comment: Do you want to mock him?

Comment: I would just say "Dr. X," as the salutation and continue the email from there. I don't usually put "Hello" or "Dear" in formal contexts. You are addressing them by their title this way and it doesn't carry any of the connotations of other modifying words.

Comment: Learn to call them by their first name. You are no longer in the culture in which you were raised and you need to respect the norms of where you are.

Comment: How does she sign her emails?  Adopting the same form she uses to identify herself is generally best/safest.

Comment: If it's France, bonjour [name] (but you'd have to get comfy with using their first name) or Cher [first name] or Salut [with or without their first name], or for the maximum formality, Madame [surname].

Comment: Also want to add, people rarely use the professional distinctions here in France. I never see Dear Dr / Professor X. I'd go with Madame X.

Comment: Who the hell uses "dear" in professional mails anyway? Am I the only one who thinks this sounds way too intimate? That's how I'd address a very close family member, not a professional contact.

Comment: @Davor: That's certainly not a universal rule. Depending on the level of familiarity between business partners dealing with each other, it's used, and appropriate. To give just one example: if you're in sales, and your firm has a conference, you might invite the people in your sales account with "Dear Jim, ..." Similarly, an adviser requesting a favor from a student (say, to cover for them) might bring across a warm familiarity like this. That said, I agree with you in most cases; it's just not a rule never to deviate from (no to say, in France, even "Tres chere Madame X" isn't uncommon).

Comment: @Davor: I'm looking at the first page of my email client. Email from a conference: "Dear Dr. Argerami,  " ; email from another conference: "Dear Colleague,"; email from my department head: "Dear Colleagues,"; etc.

Comment: "Dear professor" would have been an appropriate choice but she doesn't have any teaching duties and is a full time researcher." Teaching doesn't have anything to do with it she is still a professor. Call her Dr X or Professor X, and let her make the first move to tell you "PLease, call me Boss" or whatever she wants the young'uns to call her.

Comment: @neuronet "she is still a professor" Why? In fact chances are she is a 'Directrice de recherche,' which is rather more prestigious.

Comment: @quid Exactly, she is designated as 'Directrice de recherche.'

Comment: OK then it's different where I am. I just know "Boss" is ... bad for all the reasons already given. Err on the side of formality, and then give them the chance to correct it. I have no problem when my students call me 'Doctor X' and then I say 'Call me Z'. It shows they respect me, and I appreciate that. If they aim too low, and take too much familiarity, and treat me like their frat brothers or whatever, I find that annoying. Especially females often have people show them a lack of respect in academia because of sexism, so err on opposite.

Comment: @gnometorule, martinargerami - this is probably very region dependent. I'm in Eastern Europe, and addressing someone as "dear" here would be, to say the least, very strange.

Comment: When in doubt, a little deferential formality shows professionalism.  "Dear/Hello/Hi Prof./Dr. ______".  When you get a response, depending on how they close out the message, it's safe to use whatever they use: "Prof. Smith", "John", etc.  If it's still ambiguous, stay formal until told otherwise.

Comment: Email is an informal medium. "Formal email" is a contradiction in terms. If you wish to communicate formally with your adviser, write her a letter.

Comment: @MikeScott - that is a complete and utter nonsense.

Comment: "Dear Boss" would come across a little weird. I've usually used something like "Hello Professor X", if it's a not-too-formal email, otherwise it's just "Professor X" or similar.

Comment: @JackAidley «Learn to call them by their first name» which is considered **very impolite** in many EU countries when referring to professors or academics which are higher than your level, unless they are your friends. Scandinavian countries being a notable exception (which surprised me when I was in Denmark).

Comment: @JackAidley I would agree if this were the opposite way around - but there is precisely zero harm in being "too" formal. I would argue one can't even be _too_ formal; only perhaps _unnecessarily_ formal. There's no reason or requirement to respect norms that would be a lowering of standards. That said, I would personally consider "boss" rather informal, at least colloquial. Nobody can fault OP for using correct title though: "Dr Smith" would be my choice.

Comment: "Dear boss" would surely make her chuckle! I would find it inappropriate but rather endearing.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: I can speak to all countries, but certainly in the UK, Germany and Scandanavia it's the case that first names are normal, and from the question, I would assume France also. The point is to adapt to the local questions.

Comment: @OllieFord: I strongly disagree that there is zero harm. You mark yourself as an outsider who does not understand the local culture and you build unnecessary barriers between yourself and your supervisor by doing so.

Comment: @JackAidley I assume then that you're also in the UK. Personally I bat far more eyelids when I hear faculty referred to by first name, or surname sans title. It's rude. I hardly think I've ever been marked as an outsider not understanding local culture in my own country.

Comment: There are a lot of questions, especially on academia, that are only here because the poster has COMPLETELY OVERTHOUGHT the problem. I think people in academia tend to do that, rather than using 'gut feel' or 'common sense'. Simple - be OPEN and HONEST with your colleague. If you are not sure of the cultural way of addressing her in emails THEN TELL HER THAT, and ask her how she would like to be addressed. How do I say this...? Be open and honest. What if my boss thinks this...? Be open and honest. But what if...? Be open and honest. Don't walk on eggshells around everyone - get to the point.

Comment: Address your advisor like a boss, sir.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have noted, you should err on the side of formality. If your advisor has a doctorate, use "Dear Dr. X" (or the French equivalent).

If not, use "Dear Prof. X". While you said that she does not have teaching responsibilities, that does not preclude the title of professor. At least in the United States, there are research professors. Additionally, someone would be unlikely to be offended to be thought a professor.

As noted by @hoyland, women are often addressed as Ms. (or Miss or Mrs.) when a male colleague would be addressed as "Dr." or "Prof.", which understandably irks them.

As a professor, the way I signal to students that it's okay to use my first name is to sign emails from them with just my first name. If your advisor does that with you, you may safely address her by her first name. If she uses her initials or full name, stick with the formal form.

As noted by others, it would also be okay for you to ask how to address her. If I were you, I would remind her that I am from another culture. For example, you might say: "In India, I would address you 'Prof. X'. Is that correct in France too?" For someone not from a different culture, it can be awkward to answer their question by saying they should stick to the formal form. (Imagine the awkwardness if you asked someone if you could use their first name and they said no.)

Comment: My adviser always sign emails by her first name. Marking this as answer, I think this summed up main points in the answers with an additional *read between the lines* advise.

Comment: '"Dear Dr. X" (or the French equivalent)' There is no French equivalent as titles are usually just not used in this way (irrespective of gender), except for **medical** doctors. Moreover, it was explained in comments that this person just is no professor but something else, which is generally considered as somewhat better than the equivalent of a (full) professor. Would you propose to call a senior researcher working at, say, Microsoft research a professor?  But, yes, the person is unlikely to take offense if it happens, still it's just an incorrect way to address them.

Comment: @quid Thanks for providing the French perspective. My knowledge is limited to the United States, where there is such a thing as a research (non-teaching) professor, and PhDs use their titles professionally.

Answer (score 91):

In my view, in academia, the word "Boss" carries a large amount of semantic baggage that you probably don't want to invoke. Although you mean it to be polite and respectful, it also has an ironic context which you may not have detected. By saying "Dear Boss" can also imply that in your opinion they are neither dear to you or deserve the respect as a superior. It is safest to avoid such salutations altogether in emails.

As others have indicated this is very culturally dependent and I think you are bringing too much of your south asian culture to a european environment. Do what the locals do and emulate other peers is the safest and wisest approach.

Comment: "Dear Boss" is almost as bad as "Hey Chief".

Comment: Dear Boss is awful. Dear Dr X, or Dear Professor X, or whatever. Reasons given for not using those make no sense (focusing on research rather than teaching: what's that have to do with it). Glad the OP asked!

Comment: @user37208 I disagree! "Dear Boss" sounds worse to me.

Comment: The only time I can imagine "Dear Boss" not being weird is if it's aa very friendly relationship and you regularly use "Boss" in person in that playful and slightly ironic way.

Comment: @user37208: Hey Chief sounds pretty playful to me; Dear Boss sounds almost passive-aggressive.

Comment: Your answer addressed the issue, but I think the answer by @JoErNanO clarified my doubts in full and I find it most helpful, therefore marking that as an accepted answer.

Comment: ** also true outside of academia, this just isn't a thing you say and sounds worse than awkward.

Answer (score 44):

"Dear Professor X" is still probably still appropriate. Even if they are a full-time researcher and aren't teaching, their official position is probably some variant of "Professor." If their job title is **not** professor, then I would just go with "Dear Dr. X" and accept that it might be a little too formal.

At least in the US, I would pretty much never use "Dear Boss," even in an email sent to my actual boss in industry. It sounds awkward and weirdly removed. If you want something more formal than a first name, stick to "Ms./Mr./Dr. X."

Comment: Note that there is a difference between Europe and the US regarding who can be called "Professor": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor#Description

Comment: As a side note to the "weirdly removed" part -- if you have a close relationship with your boss, and you actually call him "boss" in conversation, then salutations like "Dear Boss," would be fine for something informal like a get-well card, a quick status update, or invitation to a barbecue. In a formal context, probably not so much.

Comment: 'their official position is probably some variant of "Professor." ' No, in France there is a separate  system for pure researchers.

Comment: Avoid "Ms X". People have a tendency to write "Ms X" for a woman when they'd write "Dr X" for a man.

Comment: @hoyland If they have a doctorate then obviously you should use "Dr." (something that is true for both women and men). But I was making a more general statement; for someone without a doctorate "Ms." is generally the best option.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_X

Answer (score 43):

The first thing to do is to ask your supervisor what she wants to be called. Does she want to keep things formal? Does she want to be called by name? **Whatever she tells you is the appropriate salutation to use with her.** There is no need to second-guess yourself, nor to go spend too much time over-thinking this.

Now, I know that cultural differences are hard to combine. For this reason I'll give you some pointers based on personal experience. In general, the French culture is one of extreme politeness when it comes to communication. The way people go about this is to use formal pronouns and conjugations when talking to each other. In other words, you'd address your interlocutor as second person plural *vous*. This is all true until one of the two, usually the one's that higher up in the hierarchy/respect scale (your manager/your spouse's parents), actually tells you "*on peut se/tu peux me [tutoyer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tutoyer#French)*" which means "we/you can use the informal pronoun *tu*", as opposed to [*vouvoyer*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vouvoyer) which is what you were initially doing. *Tu* is the second person singular.

When it comes to titles, the French don't really seem to be fussy about them. Indeed, the main titles used are Monsieur and Madame, i.e. Mr and Mrs (there is also Mademoiselle (Ms) for nubile women, although it's kind of deprecated since it's virtually impossible to safely gauge if one is married or not after they reach adulthood). Medical Doctors here are referred to as Monsieur/Madame, the Prime Minister is Monsieur Valls, the President de la République is Monsieur Hollande.

Therefore, regardless of whether your supervisor is or is not a professor, has or doesn't have teaching assignments, the formal way of addressing her would be "Madame Xyz". Which, in your email would become "*Chère Madame Xyz,*" or "Dear Mrs. Xyz". If however, Madame Xyz explicitly told you to use her first name Asd then a "*Bonjour Asd,*" or "Hello Asd," will do.

The title "Boss" is in no way appropriate nor more polite than *Madame*. I would not use it in this context, nor anywhere else in general.

Comment: +1 This is one of only two answers that actually addresses the specific situation of the OP beyond the -- admittedly useful -- response that "Hey boss" is usually inappropriate in academia.

Comment: "Dear Mrs. Xyz": I would advice against that, as "Mrs" (contrary to the French "Madame") is exclusively reserved for married women (and "Miss" is for unmarried women). Use the neutral "Ms" instead!

Comment: "you'd address your interlocutor as second person plural" like in English, where it is so common the singular got even forgotten ;-)

Comment: @quid Verily, thou art most mistaken

Comment: +1. A few notes: if the mail is in French then "Madame" or "Bonjour" will be fine. "Bonjour" is less formal but good enough. I would not use "Chère Madame XYZ". "Boss" or any translation one may come with is never appropriate, except if someone is very, very familiar with his or her boss, and only on 1:1 emails.

Answer (score 31):

Personally I cannot think of *any* context where 'Dear Boss' is appropriate. You also note that it is not customary to refer to ones advisor as 'boss' at all. There's a good reason for that: generally they are not your boss. They are your advisor, mentor, teacher, collaborator, colleague... but for most PhD students they are not in a position of being employed with their advisor as line manager.

Answer (score 28):

As a PhD student in France, I think using word "boss" would be probably taken as an inappropriate expression. If you speak in English with your professor, it is appropriate to say "Dear professor" as it is mentionned in other comments and answers.

If you speak in French, you could use "bonjour madame/monsieur" (which is equivalent to "hello sir" in English)

As there exists a formal and informal way to say "you" in French, if your advisor uses "tu" (informal you in french), you could also say him/her "tu" because otherwise, it can be considered as you would like to put a distance.

If your advisor says "vous" (formal you in french) when she/he speaks with you, you are also asked to use "vous" as it is a social norm in France.

Answer (score 5):

The formality is not important, more important is the content of the letter/e-mail. However, some people tend to consider themselves as respectable, so using formal language Dear Professor X or Dear Dr. X is advisable.

Answer (score 5):

Ask her how she would like to be addressed.  Will not cause offence and shows a cultural sensitivity.

Answer (score 4):

`When in Rome, do as a Romans do`

Find some trusted native French phd students. Study some of their mails. Write the salutation the way they do.

I am an Indian living in India and I find hi/hello too informal when talking to my seniors. Calling them by their first name cannot be even thought of according to my culture!

I write the mails as follows:

> Greetings,
>
> I wish to inform you about ...

Comment: Are you Indian in India or Indian elsewhere? Formality depends on where you are, not who you are.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius  don't agree with sentence "Calling them by their first name cannot be even thought of!". There are professors ask to their PhD students to call them by their first name.

Comment: @optimalcontrol I was talking about India. We do not call our seniors by name.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to doing a PhD in France! I think the main difficulty in your question comes from the fact that **your boss is not actually your boss**, she's firstly **your colleague**. (The closest thing you would get as a boss would be the university Dean.) She is an advisor, being senior means she has probably good advice to give and you should listen to it, but still this is really different from, say, a course where the professor is above his/her students.

This is the first point, the second is that in academia in France, all colleagues communicate informally among themselves (with one big exception in medicine). So you're expected to communicate informally with her. Not doing so is acceptable in the short term as you are foreign, and it is understandable that this type of communication is awkward to you, but in the long run it will sound bad. If you keep using formal tone, it will sound like "I agree to do what you tell me because you're the boss and I have no choice"

So definitely no "Dear Boss". Using  "Greetings" or "Good afternoon" are a good compromise until you feel comfortable enough to write "Hi Firstname,".

Answer (score 2):

It's quite interesting to see all the advocates for starting an email with "Dear ...". I'm not sure if it's a cultural difference or not, but every formal and professional email I have sent to or received from a colleague/supervisor/associate over the last 10+ years has always started with "Good Morning/Afternoon/Evening" depending on the time it was written.

If the supervisor is the main recipient or only recipient, then there's no need to include their name in the greeting (likewise, if it's a group email) - the fact that they are receiving it means that they're the intended recipient.

Less formal emails are usually begun with a "Hi xxx".

I have only seen "Dear xxx" used when a formal, written letter is sent.

Answer (score 2):

Both "Dear Madam" and "Dear Madam X" are appropriate, "Dear Boss" sounds bad to my ears. No need to use "Doctor" or "Professor", in France academic diplomas are usually not mentionned excepted in a resume.

Ho and by the way, I'm French ;)

Comment: "Dear Madam X" is wrong in English; whether or not one should address somebody as "Dr Foo" or "Prof. Foo" is very culture-dependent.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sure, that's what he asks for so my answer is focused on french culture.

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction is that "Dear Boss" is not ok (especially since she is female and that there is this word "bossy" with all the negative connotations, especially when applied to women and girls). I also would suggest a simple "Dear Ms. Lastname" or "Dear Firstname Lastname".

However, since you'll be communicating via email frequently you may also use the same salutation as you use when you meet her in person. If you greet her personally with "Hi Boss", and that's ok with you both, you may well use it in an email and it or "Dear Boss" should also be ok. But the advice in this last paragraph has to be taken with a grain of salt since I do not really know many detail about your relationship.

Comment: As a PhD advisor will almost always have a doctorate herself, I do not believe that "Ms Lastname" is appropriate. Either one is formal, and uses Dr Lastname, or informal and uses Firstname.

Comment: @arno I don't agree. Unless you would call her Dr Lastname in person, writing this in an email would sound strange to me.

Comment: My comment is independent of the mode of communication: If a person has a doctorate, then Mr/Ms/Mrs should be replaced by Dr (unless they are a surgeon, afaik).

Comment: @Arno Different cultures have different levels of formality, both in range and number. At least in the German speaking sphere, there is definitely a distinct level of "Lieber Herr X" between "Sehr geehrter Herr Professor/Dr. X" (depending on the title) and "Hallo Y", which would be quite appropriate for (symmetric!) communication between advisor and advisee.

Comment: @Arno This approach is *really* uncommon in Germany. Only very few students in the first semester would call be "Dr Lorenz" (this basically never happens) and some more call me "Prof Lorenz" in person. In email, however, both is much more common, but "Herr Lorenz" is as common and also generally seen as polite. I do not think that I have any colleague who would view  "Herr Lastname" as impolite.

Comment: @Arno especially as it is about France, Ms Lastname  should be fine as it is just not common to use Dr Name.

Comment: I believe this is about language, not about country. In German, Herr/Frau is not dropped when a title is added, in English, it is. Thus, "Herr Lastname" works as being in between "Herr Doktor Lastname" and "Firstname". However, this is different in English, where Mr/Ms/Mrs is replaced by a title. Calling a non-surgeon with a doctorate "Mr Lastname" in a professional setting is not appropriate. Calling him "Herr Lastname" can be.

Comment: @Arno No, it is in fact about the country or rather culture (although the *local* language plays a role in shaping this). In particular, just because a French person communicates in English does not mean they automatically follow, e.g., US customs in communication; rather I'd expect them to try to map the customs in French to English as best they can without sounding awkward. (This is definitely the case in German, where dropping titles is seen as a sign of respect towards a colleague -- you are not "putting the title between you", if you will.)

Comment: Let alone that in Austria (which is somehow a German speaking country) the title replaces the lastname and not the "Herr", so you would say "Sehr geehrter Herr Doktor" and not "Sehr geehrter Doktor Lastname"…

Answer (score 1):

This is a case specific question! Many would argue and say "NO", others will say it "depends" (on professor/country/institution). I'm with the latter. If she is "cool" with it, it should not be a problem. When I email my advisor (on stuff regarding my project, papers, courses), I use this "Dear Prof. N", N being the **first letter** of his last name. However, when I send emails to multiple recipients (including him), I use his full last name.

Comment: Just the first letter of the last name? Isn't it a bit strange?

Comment: I can see your point, but he is totally fine with it!

Answer (score 1):

People who you meet frequently with won't like to be addressed in a formal way. Writing "Hi X, I am stuck with doing Y, I was going about it the way you told me to do in our last meeting yesterday, but this yields strange results", is preferable over "Dear Prof. Dr. X..... " because the way you need to communicate the issues you need to be talking about necessarily requires an informal way of communication and then starting with "Dear Prof. Dr. X" is rather unnatural.

To the advisor it is just like getting an email from a good friend who instead of saying "Hello, how are you doing?" as he or she would always do when speaking on the phone or meeting in person writes "Dear Prof X". So, this is totally unnatural after you know the person and have had some meetings with each other.

Now, all social guidelines will have exceptions e.g. [this looks like an exceptional professor](https://profhugodegaris.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/cosmismdeism.pdf), but I think you're better off communicating in an informal way with your advisor.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest one of the following?

- No salutation at all. That is, just get on with what you want to say. This is quite common in emails these days. Example:

  > Regarding my thesis, I have a couple of questions. (blah blah)
  >
  > Regards, Sathyam
- Just say "Hi,". Example:

  > Hi,
  >
  > Regarding my thesis, I have a couple of questions. (blah blah)
  >
  > Regards, Sathyam

  Modify for the usual greeting in your language, eg. Bonjour
- Use her surname. Example:

  > Hi Ms. Chevalier,
  >
  > Regarding my thesis, I have a couple of questions. (blah blah)
  >
  > Regards, Sathyam

---

I answer quite a few questions on forums, effectively being a similar thing to answering questions about academic issues. I find too much formality irritating. In particular:

- Dear Nick  (would prefer just "Nick")
- Dear Gammon (would prefer to be called "Nick")
- Gammon (sounds like being told off by my teacher)
- Sir Nick (sounds like I have just been knighted)
- Mr. Nick (sounds wrong, it's Mr. Gammon, if we are going to use Mister at all)

Comment: -1. Emails with no salutation (except from one's closest friends or colleagues) are really annoying. To me they are a way of saying "I don't know how I should refer to you and don't have the courage to pick one out of the small number of available options, so I will signal my cluelessness by just not saying anything". Given that this is indeed precisely the situation here, and the OP is actively trying to NOT send such a signal of cluelessness, this is pretty much the worst advice you can offer him.

Comment: I've checked some recent unsolicited personal messages (emails). About 80% just launch into what they want. A couple use "Hi Nick", one "Hi Mr. Gammon", one uses "Hello there", a couple use just "Nick", a couple "Hey Nick". I think there is a difference in being clueless about how to address someone face-to-face, and just keeping an email brief and to the point. Sometimes when I write to customer-service departments I use "Hi there", or "Hello there" myself, not knowing exactly the name of the person who will read it.

Answer (score -2):

In North America – British professors to the contrary notwithstanding – an email between two people in the same institution (physically or otherwise) is considered to be of the same format as an interoffice memo. [Please note that like an interoffice memo one can see to whom it is being sent without a salutation and one can see who it is from without a complementary close.]

Of course it is the nature of the French to make sure that they do not do anything as it is done in other countries.  So, although the North American protocol seems logical to we Vulcans, the best I can say is viva la difference.

```
                                     Herr Professor Doctor Robert D. Jewell
```

Comment: I have no clue what you mean to say "Herr Professor Doctor Robert D. Jewell" as it would be very uncommon to use this construct  in French and even in German too, though maybe less so.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question at all.The question asks about what salutation to use and you don't address that issue even slightly.